# Android equivalent to .Net WebClient.uploadFileAsync

Tags: .net, android, asynchronous, webclient, asyncfileupload

I am looking to send a file on android asyncronously. Using c#, I would use WebClient.uploadFileAsync. I found the Java equivelent... AsyncHttpClient. However, I find this cannot be used in Android. I want to be able to get the progress of the upload. More importantly though I dont want to load the whole file in memory; the files are large images and they have trouble uploading all at once.

So my question is simple, is there an Android alternative to .Net's WebClient.uploadFileAsnyc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 2.3 and higher, use `DownloadManager`. In Android 2.2 or lower, you would need to roll it more yourself using `HttpClient` or something.

Comment: I am ending up taking the easy route, I am going to send chunks of the file through a webservice. This will solve the memory and the progress bar issues. Thanks for the info though.